# avro code generation /Dynamic typing

Tags: avro

This might be a silly question, but can anyone explain to me what is meant by dynamic typing ,code generation in context to AVRO ? . I am pretty new to AVRO and would really appreciate if someone can help me in detail to understand this.

Also , AVRO has a datatype named fixed, what would be a practical scenario to use this data type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code generation refers to the code which we generate based on our file schema using avro tools. So when you say serialize/deserialize the data without code generation then it means you rae including the schema in your program and vice-versa. You can read more from https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.7/gettingstartedjava.html#Serializing+and+deserializing+without+code+generation